# Ordering N elements into columns, via ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have a bit of a head-scratcher on my hands.

I'm using ng-repeat to output a list of items that are positioned inside a widget.

The widgets are resizable, with three available sizes. The first two are only wide enough to have one column of elements, so displaying them in the correct order is trivial. However, when the widget is expanded to twice width, more elements are displayed at 50% of the width. The elements are arranged by default using `display:inline-block; float: left` which means that I end up with the ordering going from left -> right, whereas I need them to be ordered vertically.

Initially I was performing two ng-repeats with a column wrapper around each, using splice to split the results, however this causes problems with ordering, because each set of elements is only ordered relative to its container column.

So here's some stripped down code from one of the widgets:

```
<div class="item review" ng-repeat="review in reviews | orderBy:'date':true | limitTo:14">
  <div class="header">
    ...
  </div>
 <div class="body">
  <div class="comment">
    <p>{{review.comments}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would quite happily use ng-if alongside an $index comparison, something like `ng-if="($index+1)==7"` on the element I'd like to insert before a group, but since the ng-repeat is on the items themselves, I can't wrap them with that method.

I've tried various ideas with no real success so far. There are things I can do outside of Angular but it's messy and I would like to keep in within Angular, I'm sure what I'm after is possible. Can somebody save me?

EDIT: Illustration of what I mean

[image]

Comment: Not a css expert, but would using `ng-repeat` on all of your (up to if I understand correctly?) 14 elements and giving a class to your 8th element to break the column and be entered to the right column work?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure I understand the point you're trying to make.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your problem. Is it you are having trouble ordering elements vertically on a widget? It comes out ordering them horizontally? (meaning row 1. a, b; row 2. c,d etc..)

Comment: How about wrapping an `ng-repeat` like you said on the outside to perform as a counter and then you would be able to use your `($index+1)==7` condition?

Comment: Sounds to me like what you really want to use is [CSS columns](http://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/lP3vc57k98gPUEbShHWT

You can use css3 `column-count` or its shorthand `columns`:

```
ul {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I can't believe I'd never heard of this!